# Delete method issue - Asp.net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a POST Method which is working fine
it takes a list of object and add it to the database with Entity Framework AddRange

I tried to apply the same logic with the DELETE method (takes list of objects and delete it from the database with RemoveRange) it does return 200 OK but does not delete from the database

POST

```
[HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(List<Provider_status> rows)
        {
            try
            {
                using (DbModel dbModel = new DbModel())
                {
                    dbModel.Provider_status.AddRange(rows);
                    dbModel.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch { }
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent("Records Added")
            };
        }
```

DELETE method

```
[HttpDelete]
        public HttpResponseMessage Delete(List<Provider_status> rows)
        {
            try
            {
                using (DbModel dbModel = new DbModel())
                {
                    dbModel.Provider_status.RemoveRange(rows);
                    dbModel.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch { }
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent("Records Deleted")
            };
        }
```

Comment: "not working" is not a detailed enough problem statement to be able to answer.

Comment: updated to: it does return 200 OK but does not delete from the database

Comment: Are you missing the `[HttpDelete]` attribute from the action?

Comment: i added `HttpDelete` but same results

Comment: You are catching and ignoring any error (exception), could you be missing important things the system is telling you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach ( var row in rows)
{
var exRow= dbModel.Provider_status.FirstOrDefault(i=> i.Id==row.Id);
if( exRow!=null) dbModel.Provider_status.Remove(exRow);
}
dbModel.SaveChanges();
```

and IMHO remove [HttpDelete] from the action

Comment: i got 2 error 1) Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'bool' 2) Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Comment: It was a typo. You have to use ==  instead =

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause is that

`dbModel.Provider_status.RemoveRange(rows);`

Is comparing `rows` to `Provider_status` using [reference equality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/equality-comparisons#reference-equality) and considering that since none match, none should be removed.

Comment: any idea how to fix that to be able to delete from the database